# How to share content and files with other users within the site (not in facebook or other social media)?

Tags: 7, users

Users would like to be able to share content with other users within the site (not on Facebook or any other social media).

For example, if I read a blog that I like and think my colleague would be interested I could click 'SHARE' and send it to another user's profile or work e-mail address. Or tag someone? This would require a notification to the user that they have shared or tagged in something.

It would be great to be able to do this with blog posts, files, photos, and videos. "

Answer (score 1):

Besides the custom approach identified above, you may also want to look into using the Forward module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/forward

It includes some basic tracking for reports as well.